# Checking intersections of line Segments from a list of line segments in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a Class "Polygon" to show the type of Polygon whether it is simple (concave or convex) or complex. For this I created a list of line segments from the vertices given for the Polygon in the main program.
Then I created functions "ccw" and "intersection" to detect whether two line segments intersect or not.
Now what i want is, a function, that should check intersections for all line segments present in a list. The function, starting from Line Segment (LS) 3, should check the intersection of LS 3 and LS 1....Then intersection of LS 4 with LS 2 and LS 1....Then intersection of LS 5 with LS 3, LS 2, and LS 1 and so on.... But for the very last Line Segment in the list, it should not check the intersection with LS 1 because Last LS would be joined with LS 1 (to create a closed polygon) and will always show intersection, which is not required. So, for the Last Line Segment, the function should skip the check of intersection with Line Segment 1.

```
class Polygon:
    def __init__(self,*vertices):        
        self.vertices = [Polygon.Point(v[0],v[1]) for v in vertices] #Vertices of a polygon
    
    @property
    def lines(self):      
    #Retun list of all line segments of Polygon        
        return [Polygon.LSeg(self.vertices[i], self.vertices[(i+1)%len(self.vertices)]) for i in range(len(self.vertices))]      
    
    @property
    def shape(self):
        #THIS IS WHAT I HAVE TRIED BUT IT RETURNS "COMPLEX" FOR EVERY POLYGON#      
        for i in range(2,len(self.lines)):            
            for j in range(2, i+1):                
                if i == len(self.lines)-1 and j == i-1:                   
                   pass                
                elif self.intersect(self.lines[i], self.lines[i-j]):                    
                   return 'Complex'
    def ccw(self,A,B,C):        
         return (C.y-A.y)*(B.x-A.x) > (B.y-A.y)*(C.x-A.x)
    def intersect(self, L1,L2):
         return self.ccw(L1.p1,L2.p1,L2.p2) != self.ccw(L1.p2,L2.p1,L2.p2) and self.ccw(L1.p1,L1.p2,L2.p1) != self.ccw(L1.p1,L1.p2,L2.p2)    
    
    class LSeg:     #Line Segment Class
        def __init__(self,p1,p2):            
            self.p1=p1          
            self.p2=p2    

    class Point:       
        def __init__(self,x,y):            
            self.x=x            
            self.y=y

poly1 = Polygon((2,7), (10,1),  (8,6), (11,7), (7,10)) #Simple Polygon

poly2 = Polygon((0.65,0.92), (-1,-3), (4,-2), (3,2), (4,3), (6,2), (5,0)) #Complex Polgon  
print(poly1.shape)
print(poly2.shape)
```

Comment: Could try re-writing this explanation: "Line Segment (LS) 3, should check the intersection of LS 3 with LS 1....LS 4 with LS 2 and LS 1....LS 5 with LS 3, LS 2, and LS 1 and so on...."? I don't understand your desired behavior.

Comment: @Ian Look, in a polygon, if at least any two line segments intersect, then the Polygon is complex. Now while checking for any intersection b/w two line segments we should be careful for two consecutive line segments. For example, line segment AB (or call it LS 1) is joined with line segment BC (or call it LS 2) at point B, so we should not check for these line segments. Similarly, line segment BC intersets line segment CD at point C (because both are consecutive line segments). So in short we should try not to check for teo consecutive line segments.

Comment: .....(continued)....A better approach is to start our checking from line segment 3 (3rd element of the list of line segments) and check it's intersection with line segment 1 (1st element of the list). Similarly,  the intersection of LS 4 will be checked with LS 2 and LS 1.... intersection of LS 5 will be checked with LS 3, LS 2, LS 1. Now for the last line segment (last element of the list) its intersection should not be checked with first line segments (because both are consecutive lines). I hope now you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code below, I added a class method that checks whether two LSegs share an endpoint. I simply use that to avoid checking for intersections between segments with a shared endpoint.

Note my user of [_*iter*_()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__)

```
class Polygon:
    def __init__(self, *vertices):
        self.vertices = [Polygon.Point(v[0], v[1]) for v in vertices]  # Vertices of a polygon

    @property
    def lines(self):
        # Retun list of all line segments of Polygon
        return [Polygon.LSeg(self.vertices[i], self.vertices[(i + 1) % len(self.vertices)]) for i in
                range(len(self.vertices))]

    @property
    def shape(self):
        for base_line in self.lines:
            for line in self.lines:
                if not line.shares_end(base_line) and self.intersect(base_line, line):
                    return 'Complex'

    def ccw(self, A, B, C):
        return (C.y - A.y) * (B.x - A.x) > (B.y - A.y) * (C.x - A.x)

    def intersect(self, L1, L2):
        return self.ccw(L1.p1, L2.p1, L2.p2) != self.ccw(L1.p2, L2.p1, L2.p2) and self.ccw(L1.p1, L1.p2,
                                                                                           L2.p1) != self.ccw(L1.p1,
                                                                                                              L1.p2,
                                                                                                              L2.p2)

    class LSeg:  # Line Segment Class
        def __init__(self, p1, p2):
            self.p1 = p1
            self.p2 = p2

        def __iter__(self):
            yield self.p1
            yield self.p2

        def __repr__(self):
            return f'({self.p1} | {self.p2})'

        def shares_end(self, other):
            for point in other:
                if point in self:
                    return True
            return False

    class Point:
        def __init__(self, x, y):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y

        def __repr__(self):
            return f'({self.x}, {self.y})'


poly1 = Polygon((2, 7), (10, 1), (8, 6), (11, 7), (7, 10))  # Simple Polygon

poly2 = Polygon((0.65, 0.92), (-1, -3), (4, -2), (3, 2), (4, 3), (6, 2), (5, 0))  # Complex Polgon
print(poly1.shape)
print(poly2.shape)
```

Outputs:

```
None
Complex
```

Comment: Ooo Thank you so much Sir!!! ❤️ Thank God you understood my question, because other people were not getting my issue, that what i actually wanted.